# Is it possible to pass data to a css file?

Tags: php, html, css, symfony

I am coding a CMS in php and would like to know if it is possible to pass a url to an image, I have my php pages coding with Twig template and I am using `{{ image1url }}` to echo the image url, but is it possible to pass that url to the css file? something like below...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ config['website']['web_address'] }}/themes/{{ config['template']['theme'] }}/{{ config['template']['css_folder'] }}/all.css?image_url={{ config['website']['image_url'] }}" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes that is possible, you have to make sure that php parses css extensions. It's in the apache config I think. (or whatever server software you are using)

An other solution might be to have inline css, which will be parsed by the php parser.